# How to evaluate data type (i.e. str, int, double... etc.) when reading text file

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, text

I am reading in information from a text file which has been ripped from a pdf, so everything is a mess.

Some example variables (columns) that I'm trying to separate include date, action type and summary.

For date, the format is DD/MM/YY, so I know that the first index will always be an int. However, whenever I test the file (using type(xyz)), everything is marked as being an str.

How do I get python to recognize what is, and what is not, a str vs. int vs. double... etc.?

Comment: When you read text from a file **everything** is a string. If you want to parse that string into numbers, dates, etc., you will have to do so explicitly. But *"how can I parse text?"* is way too broad a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use regular expressions and recast the  string sections.

Long answer: it's because all of this is coming from a text file, so everything *is* a string. The date 23/10/90 isn't represented in a .txt as a numerical value, it's a collection of character codes. Depending on exactly what you are trying to get out of that file, your best bet is to regex out the data you want, and recast it. So, for dates, try `int(dayString)` `int(monthString)` etc.